# I've made a carousel in bootstrap and pasted it in my wordpress theme but the slides stack. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming, carousel

So I've made a carousel with Bootstrap and pasted it in my wordpress theme. I've tried to combine it with some WP code, I hope you guys can help me.

```
  <div class="carousel-inner text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('wide');?>" class="d-block w-100"> 
          <h2 class="carousel-caption bg-black w-auto font-weight-bold font-italic">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h2>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included jQuery, check console for errors.

Comment: I've checked, but there is no errors in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I'v figured it out

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide pt-4" data-ride="carousel">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li> 
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>1, 'tag'=>'favorite')); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('wide');?>" class="d-block w-100"> 
          <h2 class="carousel-caption bg-black w-auto font-weight-bold font-italic">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>3, 'tag'=>'favorite', 'offset'=>1)); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('wide');?>" class="d-block w-100"> 
          <h2 class="carousel-caption bg-black w-auto font-weight-bold font-italic">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </h2>
        </a>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```